# Bind to Specific Property inside each Item in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datacontext, itemscontrol

Purely for code and template simplification I want to be able to have each item inside my items control bound to a property inside each array element. For example

```
public List<MyObject> MyObjectList;  //If I bind to this, each item recieves MyObject as its data context.
```

I want the ability for each item to recieve MyObject.SomeProperty as its data context. I thought through setting ItemContainerStyle I could set the datacontext but that doesn't appear to work. Does anybody have any ideas?

Somthing along the lines of the following, so each Item is bound to the Property "FieldValue" inside of each object. But in this case, it grabs the "FieldValue" binding from the root object, not each individual item.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyArrayOfObjects, ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyObjectTemplateSelector}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Control.DataContext" Value="{Binding FieldValue}"/>
                    </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `ItemTemplate` change `DataContext` of root element like `<Grid ... DataContext="{Binding FieldValue}">`

Comment: How does this combine with the ItemTemplateSelector?

Comment: You need to add `DataContext="{Binding FieldValue}"` to root element of each template where you want it to work like that

Comment: Thats what I wanted to avoid. But if this is the only solution....